# Data mining course grades

Tags: bayesian

What I want:

I am doing some data mining on the final grade components of various courses. I would like to find correlations among clicker, tutorials, homework on the performance in the final exam. I have the marks for all these components.

My naive attempts:

I have plotted of these variables and extracted the Pearson correlation coefficient and this has worked for some components that have a normal distribution, however most of these components do not have a normal distribution, but instead are upper bounded, for instance max. total clicker mark is one, so most students got marks between 0.6-1.0.

Question:
Is it possible to obtain any sort of relation between these variables using one of the non-parametric tests, and which one should I use?

Options:
I have been suggested bayesian model averaging for this analysis. Why should this be a more adequate way of analyzing my data?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Pearson's correlation does not require normally distributed data.